# Cannot access static inner classes from another package

Tags: java, nested

java version "1.8.0_45"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)

I have the following class in this package.

The class is used to populate objects from a json string using gson (works ok). So the class is structured this way.

```
package news.com.sample.model

public class Status {
    private String status;
    private List<Results> results;

    static class Results {
        private String title;
        private List<Multimedia> multimedia;

        static class Multimedia {
            private String url;

            public String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public List<Multimedia> getMultimedia() {
            return multimedia;
        }
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public List<Results> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try and access getMultimedia from a class that is located in another package I get the following error:

```
cannot access getMultimedia() in news.com.sample.model.Status.Results
```

The class I am using to gain access

```
package news.com.sample.data;

import news.com.sample.model.Status;

public class ParseNewsFeed {
    public ParseNewsFeed() {
        Status status = new Status();
        status.getResults().get(0).getMultimedia().get(0).getUrl());
    }
}
```

However, if I create a new class in the same package news.com.sample.model everything works ok.

Is there any way to resolve this issue, as I need to access this Status class in more than one package?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Make your `Results` class public?

Comment: Instead of default access modifier for the inner class, use public if that is not an issue

Comment: Thanks, that solved it

Comment: 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms. What you have here are static *nested* classes.

Comment: @EJP, yes you are right about the nest classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "public" before your inner static class. it's a access control issue